# SBT custom task to debug forked JVM

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to know how to make a 'debug' task in SBT that forks a JVM in suspended state to allow me to attach the debugger from an IDE.

I got this code so far:

```
lazy val Debug = config("debug") extend(Test) describedAs("Debug a running forked JVM")

lazy val debugSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    fork in Debug := true,
    javaOptions in Debug ++= Seq("-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=127.0.0.1:5005"),
    test in Debug <<= test in Test
)
```

The problem seems to be that 'javaOptions' setting is not being picked up by the 'test' task when I run "debug:test".

How can I make the 'debug' command work?